# Can an extender with USB ports be wired direct to the mains?

Tags: power-supply, usb, mains, safety, fuses

I have an extension lead that has been wired directly into the mains (there is no space behind a cupboard to plug it into the wall socket that was there).

I think this is the same situation as adding wall box extension from existing socket, and no concern.

However it has USB charge ports attached to the extender. By removing the plug and wiring it directly into the mains have I removed the fuse between these USB chargers and the mains? Is this a problem?

[image]

Comment: that powerbar may not have the necessary certification ... along with being directly connected, if your have a fire, the isurance company may have a reason not to pay a settlement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most devices like this are ‘not suitable for direct connection to the mains’ in other words they rely on the fused plug for protection, so yes what you have done is a problem.  If you can add an inline fuse somehow (and I guess 13A will be ok) then the problem is technically solved although I’m not sure whether it meets UK regs or not (probably not these days as anything permanently wired in needs to be done by a qualified electrician).

Comment: The USB part doesn’t really make a difference, even a simple 4-outlet socket strip needs a 13A fuse in its plug.

Comment: Thank you! I’ll remove and plug it in elsewhere straight away. Appreciate the advice.

Comment: I take the advice and will remove asap. However, I’m interested how this is different to a two socket walk box that could be wired in as a spur from existing wall box. Logically these seem to be the same and a wall box doesn’t have an additional fuse. 

I fully take your advice and will remove asap! I’m just interested in the difference. Thank you

Comment: It does seem counterintuitive, but does make sense.  A 2-outlet wall box will have a 2.5sq mm house wiring cable connected directly to its internal terminals (more likely a ring main in the UK) and fused at 30 or 32A at the fuse box.  A twin extension is fed by a 13A flex cable, which is perhaps 1.5sq mm and needs to be protected by a 13A fuse.  Theoretically it would be ok to have a 10A breaker in the fuse box, but the electrical regulations deliberately allow only a few simple configurations so that it’s obvious to an electrician what they’re dealing with.

Comment: I understand. Thanks very much for the full explanation!